# Getting java.lang.NumberFormatException When Outputting

Tags: java, exception, text-files, bluej

I am using `BlueJ`, for reference.

The program compiles fine. It runs fine as well except that this:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Washington,George"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at WorkerApp.main(WorkerApp.java:53)
at __SHELL112.run(__SHELL112.java:6)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:730)
```

Specifically highlighting:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Washington,George"

    at WorkerApp.main(WorkerApp.java:53)
```

The point of this program is to read a text file and add to said text file.

The program is supposed to read and open "EmployeeData.txt":

```
S       Washington,George       000001      125000
H   MacDonald,Ronald        386218     7.80 true  40
H       Walton,Samuel           268517  8.21    false
H   Thomas,David            131313  9.45    true    38
H   Sanders,HarlandDavid    277651  8.72    false
S   Baron,James         368535  310236
```

When I click on the exception it highlights this from my main class

```
double salary = Double.parseDouble(Employee[3]);
```

This is the full main class `WorkerApp` in which I am trying to read and open the text file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class WorkerApp{
/**
* Reads the infile, runs tests, and prints the output.
*/
public static void  main (String args[]){
    Company company = new Company();
    try{
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (new File("EmployeeData.txt"));
        while(reader.hasNext()){
            String line = reader.nextLine();
            String Employee[] = line.split(" ");
            String sorh = Employee[0];
            String name = Employee[1];
            String id = Employee[2];
            double salary = Double.parseDouble(Employee[3]);
            Employee e;
            if (Employee[0].equals("S")){
                e = new SalariedWorker(sorh, name, id, salary);}
            else {
                boolean overtime = Boolean.parseBoolean(Employee[4]);
                if(overtime){
                    int maxHours = Integer.parseInt(Employee[5]);
                     e = new HourlyWorker(sorh, name, id, salary, maxHours);
                }
                else{
                    e = new HourlyWorker(sorh, name, id, salary);
                }
            }
            company.add(e);
        }
    }catch (Exception err){
        //System.out.println(err);
        err.printStackTrace();
    }

    company.print();
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 1
    System.out.println("1) Add a salaried worker");
    SalariedWorker SWorker1 = new SalariedWorker("S", "Moran,Blake", "123456", 260000);
    company.add(SWorker1);
    company.print();

    //Test Number 2
    System.out.println("2) Add an hourly worker who has no overtime allowed");
    HourlyWorker HWorker1 = new HourlyWorker("H", "Bob,Billy", "654321", 15);
    company.add(HWorker1);
    company.print();

    //Test Number 3
    System.out.println("3) Add an hourly worker who has overtime allowed");
    HourlyWorker HWorker2 = new HourlyWorker("H", "Smith,Will", "345612", 10.5, 30);
    company.add(HWorker2);
    company.print();

    //Test Number 4
    System.out.println("4) Add a worker that is already in the database");
    try{
        company.add(SWorker1);
    }catch(Exception err){
        System.out.println(err);
        System.out.println();
    }   

    //Test Number 5
    System.out.println("5) Print the sorted list");
    company.print();

    //Test Number 6
    System.out.println("6) Remove a worker who is NOT in the list");
    company.remove("Brooks,Phil");
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 7
    System.out.println("7) Remove a worker who is the first in the list ");
    company.remove("Moran,Blake");
    company.print();
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 8
    System.out.println("8) Find a worker who is the middle of the list");
    int index = company.find("Bob,Billy");
    System.out.println("Found at "+ index);
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 9
    System.out.println("9) Find a worker who is NOT in the list");
    index = company.find("Harrison,Ford");
    System.out.println("Found at "+ index);
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 10
    System.out.println("10) Find the weekly salary of a worker who is salaried");
    System.out.println(SWorker1.FindSalary());
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 11
    System.out.println("11) Find the weekly salary of an hourly worker who has no overtime allowed [50 hours]");
    System.out.println(HWorker1.FindSalary(50));
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 12
    System.out.println("12) Find the weekly salary of an hourly worker who has overtime allowed [50 hours]");
    System.out.println(HWorker2.FindSalary(50));
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 13
    System.out.println("13) Find the weekly salary of an hourly worker who has overtime allowed [20 hours]");
    System.out.println(HWorker2.FindSalary(20));
    System.out.println();

    //Test Number 14
    System.out.println("14) Print the sorted list");
    company.print();

    //Test Number 15
    System.out.println("\n15) End the process");
} 
}
```

It should be noted that on top of the exception it spits out this output:

```
1) Add a salaried worker
S Moran,Blake 123456 260000.0
2) Add an hourly worker who has no overtime allowed
S Moran,Blake 123456 260000.0
H Bob,Billy 654321 15.0 false
3) Add an hourly worker who has overtime allowed
S Moran,Blake 123456 260000.0
H Bob,Billy 654321 15.0 false
H Smith,Will 345612 10.5 true 30
4) Add a worker that is already in the database
java.lang.RuntimeException: The Employee Is Not New

5) Print the sorted list
S Moran,Blake 123456 260000.0
H Bob,Billy 654321 15.0 false
H Smith,Will 345612 10.5 true 30
6) Remove a worker who is NOT in the list
The Employee is not Found

7) Remove a worker who is the first in the list 
H Bob,Billy 654321 15.0 false
H Smith,Will 345612 10.5 true 30

8) Find a worker who is the middle of the list
Found at 0

9) Find a worker who is NOT in the list
Found at -1

10) Find the weekly salary of a worker who is salaried
5000.0

11) Find the weekly salary of an hourly worker who has no overtime allowed [50 hours]
750.0

12) Find the weekly salary of an hourly worker who has overtime allowed [50 hours]
630.0

13) Find the weekly salary of an hourly worker who has overtime allowed [20 hours]
210.0

14) Print the sorted list
H Bob,Billy 654321 15.0 false
H Smith,Will 345612 10.5 true 30

15) End the process
```

If it helps, here are my other classes for reference, as they might be the source of the problem.

`Company`:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Company{
private Employee[] employeeArray;
private final int InitialCapacity = 7;
private int employCount;

/**
* Creates the employee array and sets employCount to 0.
*/
public Company(){
    employeeArray = new Employee[InitialCapacity];
    employCount = 0;
}

/**
* Finds an employee in the list.
*/
public int find(String name){
    for (int i = 0; i < employCount; i++){
        if (employeeArray[i].getName().equals(name)){
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

/**
* Adds an employee to the list.
*/
public int add(Employee employ){
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < employCount; index++){
        int result = employeeArray[index].getName().compareTo(employ.getName());
        if(result == 0){
            throw new RuntimeException ("The Employee Is Not New");
        }
    }

    if (employeeArray.length == employCount){
        expand();
    }

    employeeArray[index] = employ;
    employCount++;
    return index;
}

/**
* Removes an employee to the list.
*/
public void remove(String name){
    int index = find(name);
    if (index == -1){
        System.out.println("The Employee is not Found");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = index; i < employCount - 1; i++){
        employeeArray[i] = employeeArray[i + 1];
    }

    employCount--;
}

/**
* Prints the list.
*/
public void print(){
    if(employCount == 0){
        System.out.println("The List is Empty");
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < employCount; i++){
        System.out.println(employeeArray[i]);
    }
}

/**
* Expands the list.
*/
private void expand(){
    Employee[] newArray = new Employee[employeeArray.length + InitialCapacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < employeeArray.length; i++){
        newArray[i] = employeeArray[i];
    }

    employeeArray = newArray;
}
}
```

`Employee`:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Employee{
private String SorH;
private String name;
private String ID;

/**
* Sets sets SorH, name, and ID to SH, n, and id.
*/
public Employee (String SH, String n, String id){
    SorH = SH;
    name = n;
    ID = id;
}

/**
* Gets the first part (S or H) of the employee list.
*/
public String getSorH(){
    return SorH;
}

/**
* Gets the name of the employee list.
*/
public String getName(){
    return name;
}

/**
* Gets the ID of the employee list.
*/
public String getID(){
    return ID;
}

/**
* Sets SorH to SH.
*/
public void setSorH(String SH){
    SorH = SH;
}

/**
* Sets name to n.
*/
public void setName(String n){
    name = n;
}

/**
* Sets ID to id.
*/
public void setID(String id){
    ID = id;
}

/**
* Returns a string representing the employee list.
*/
public String toString(){
    return String.format("%s %s %s", getSorH(), getName(), getID());
}
}
```

`HourlyWorker`:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class HourlyWorker extends Employee{
private double hourlySalary;
private boolean overtime;
private int maxHours;

/**
* Contains the super and sets the hourly salary and maxHours to hourlySal and maxH and
* overtime to true.
*/
public HourlyWorker(String SH, String n, String id, double hourlySal, int maxH){
    super(SH, n, id);
    hourlySalary = hourlySal;
    overtime = true;
    maxHours = maxH;
}

/**
* Contains the super and sets the hourly salary to hourlySal and overtime to false.
*/
public HourlyWorker(String SH, String n, String id, double hourlySal){
    super(SH, n, id);
    hourlySalary = hourlySal;
    overtime = false;
}

/**
* Returns if overtime is true or false.
*/
public boolean overtime(){
    return overtime;
}

/**
* Gets the max hours of an hourly worker.
*/
public int getmaxH(){
    return maxHours;
}

/**
* Gets the hourly salary of an hourly worker.
*/
public double gethourlySalary(){
    return hourlySalary;
}

/**
* Sets hourly salary to hSalary.
*/
public void sethourlySalary (double hSalary){
    hourlySalary = hSalary;
}

/**
* Finds the weekly salary of an hourly worker.
*/
public double FindSalary(double hoursWorked){
    if (overtime){
        if (hoursWorked <= maxHours){
            return hoursWorked * hourlySalary;
        } else{
            return maxHours * hourlySalary + 
                                (hoursWorked - maxHours) * hourlySalary * 1.5;
        }
    } else{
        return hoursWorked * hourlySalary;
    }
}

/**
* Contains the super string and adds onto the string.
*/
public String toString(){
    String str = super.toString() + String.format(" %s %s", gethourlySalary(),overtime());

    if (overtime){
        str = str + String.format(" %s", getmaxH());
    }

    return str;
}
}
```

`SalariedWorker`:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class SalariedWorker extends Employee{
private double yearlySalary;

/**
* Contains the super and sets yearly salary to ySalary.
*/
public SalariedWorker(String SH, String n, String id, double ySalary){
    super(SH, n, id);
    yearlySalary = ySalary;
}

/**
* Gets the yearly salary of a salaried worker.
*/
public double getyearlySalary(){
    return yearlySalary;
}

/**
* Sets the yearly salary of a salaried worker.
*/
public void setyearlySalary(double ySalary){
    yearlySalary = ySalary;
}

/**
* Finds the weekly salary of a salaried worker.
*/
public double FindSalary(){
    return yearlySalary / 52;
}    

/**
* Contains the super string and adds onto the string.
*/
public String toString(){
    return super.toString() + String.format(" %s", getyearlySalary());
}
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Tell me, what kind of number is *Washington,George*?

Comment: Don't post your entire code. Instead create [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). There is even high chance that you will find root of your problem (so maybe even solution) while creating it so it is definitely worth putting your time to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `line.split(" ");` you might want to try `line.split("\\s+")`. I think the splitting is not happening properly.

Comment: That has made the text file finally appear in my output, thank you! The only problem now is that when I run the code, it only shows the bottom half of my output, more specifically it displays the second half of 5) and the rest. Nothing before.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have access to a debugger ? There should be one in any IDE you can use, be it Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ or ...

Just put a breakpoint on the line where exception occurs and look at the values in the Employee array. The cause of the error should then be self evident.

In case it is still not evident for you, here is next clue : read again the javadoc for [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and compare with what you have in Employee.